# Работа с git с разных компьютеров

Tags: git

Работаю с настольного и ноутбука.

Допустим я начал проект на компе, потом продолжил с ноутбука. При этом проект обновлялся бы на сервере через `git pull`.

Как сохранять изменения в проект с двух компов?

Comment: то есть, рассказать, как коммитить (commit) и пушить (push) ?

Comment: Сохранять с 2х пк точно так же как и на одном.

Comment: "При этом проект обновлялся бы на сервере через git pull" - вы явно путаетесь в терминологии. pull может быть выполнен только на локальной рабочей копии, и если вы на сервере делаете pull, то с точки зрения git эта машина такой же клиент как и остальные.

Answer (score 3):

Работа с одним репозиторием с разных компьютеров

С одним репозиторием с разных компьютеров может работать несколько разработчиков или вы сами, если например работаете над одним и тем же проектом дома и на работе.

Для получения обновлений с удаленного репозитория воспользуйтесь командой:

```
git pull
```

Если вы изменили ваши локальные файлы, то команда `git pull` выдаст ошибку. Если вы уверены, что хотите перезаписать локальные файлы, файлами из удаленного репозитория то выполните команды:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash pop
```

Вместо github подставьте название вашего удаленного репозитория, которое вы зарегистрировали командой `git push -u`.

Как мы уже знаем, для того чтобы изменения выложить на удаленный репозиторий используется команда:

```
git push
```

В случае, если в удаленном репозитории лежат файлы с версией более новой, чем у вас в локальном, то команда `git push` выдаст ошибку. Если вы уверены, что хотите перезаписать файлы в удаленном репозитории несмотря на конфликт версий, то воспользуйтесь командой:

```
git push -f
```

Иногда возникает необходимость отложить ваши текущие изменения и поработать над файлами, которые находятся в удаленном репозитории. Для этого отложите текущие изменения командой:

```
git stash
```

После выполнения этой команды ваша локальная директория будет содержать файлы такие же, как и при последнем коммите. Вы можете загрузить новые файлы из удаленного репозитория командой `git pull` и после этого вернуть ваши изменения которые вы отложили командой:

```
git stash pop
```

[Подробнее...](https://habrahabr.ru/post/273897/)

Comment: `git push -u` не регистрирует имя репозитория. Либо дефолтный `origin` при `git clone`, либо `git clone -o reponame ...`, либо `git remote add reponame ...`

Comment: `git reset --hard` - удалит все ваши изменения, такое и советовать нельзя, тем более явно неопытному пользователю

Answer (score 1):

Вам просто нужно создать удаленный репозиторий, например на Github или Bitbucket, который будет общим хранилищем для вашего проекта.

К примеру, работаете на ноуте → запушили изменения в репозиторий → пересели за комп → подтянули изменения из репозитория → сделали новые изменения → `push` в репозиторий. Потом когда нужно внести изменения на сервер делаете `pull` из этого репозитория.